# Getting DB2 FETCH not valid, cursor in unknown position after upgrade from 7.1 to 7.3

Tags: db2, db2-400, attunity

We have Attunity Replicate running which does a change data capture on the data.

The Replication works by first doing a full load of a table, then constantly updates the data using the DB2 journal.

We recently upgraded from 7.1 to 7.3, and the full load query is not working anymore.

When trying to load a table with 500k rows, it stops after 350k rows and I get the following error.

Note that this is only happening for some tables, and not all.

I have set up the waitTimeOut to be 600 seconds.

The error I get is:

> RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: 07005 NativeError: -227 Message:
>   [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0227 - FETCH not
>   valid, cursor SQL_CUR98BF6120 in unknown position.

Is there any command or something to run on the AS400 or Attunity Replicate which can sort this error message out?

Comment: Can you post one of the SQL getting error?

Comment: Are you up to date with PTFs?  Contact Attunity and/or IBM.